# in winter evenings

Tags: phrase-request, expressions

*I don't think I'll ever be able to get over the feeling of sipping a cup of hot coffee while playing video games **in winter evenings**?*

I was asked to talk about my favorite season. I said the sentence above but I'm not sure if 'in winter evenings' is correct here.

How do I say it correctly?

Comment: get over is usually used in conjunction with a bad experience (you can also check https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+over) so maybe it's not the best expression if you're talking about your favourite season

Comment: for the rest the sentence is fine, I'm not too clear on what's causing your doubts?

Comment: **On winter evenings** is more idiomatic than **in winter evenings**  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+winter+evenings%2Con+winter+evenings&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20winter%20evenings%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20winter%20evenings%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

It should be '**on** winter evenings'.

We use "on" rather than "in" when speaking about a specific date, for example:

- Yesterday, I watched TV **in** the evening.
- I watched TV **on** the evening *of December 21st*.

Although your example does not specify a date, you do name the *season* 'winter', which acts as an adjective to the main noun 'evenings', so we use the same rule as with a date.

If the season is not acting as an adjective to the word 'evening', this rule would not apply, for example:

- In summer, we would watch TV in the evenings.